# Loading an object within an add to linked list method

Tags: java, constructor, linked-list

Here is the code I am having trouble with as well as a link to the classes that I am working with https://github.com/felipeachavoya/Projects.git.

```
public void addInterest(Interest interest) {
    interest = new Interest();
    interest = interest.Interest();
    topics.add(interest);
}
```

The addInterest() method within the member class is supposed to create an instance of an interest using the class Interest, and then add that interest object into a linked list within the member class. However, when the addInterest() method is called, it also needs to  prompt the user to input the topic (String) and the level of interest to said topic (int) before that object is added to the linked list. I don't know how to do that though and when I tried using it gave me an error saying the method Interest() in the type Interest is not applicable for the arguments (). Any ideas?

EDIT: I don't know if the link I posted is working so I'm just going to post here the interest class with the two private variables and constructor method.

```
public class Interest extends Member implements Serializable {
    private String topic;
    private int level;

    public void Interest(String topic, int level) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Topic: ");
        this.topic = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Level (1 - 10): ");
        this.level = in.nextInt();

        in.close();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Please embed into the question the piece of code you are asking about. We should not have to follow any link to understand a question.

Comment: Sorry if the link isn't working, hopefully posting a snippet of the subclass im working with helps!

Comment: It is not a matter of whether the link works or not. It is just a principle on this site that all necessary information should be embedded. Thanks for having included the code into your question.

Comment: Your `Interest` method should not take any arguments. Remove those parameters from its definition; you never use them. Secondly, that method does not *return* anything, so when you call it, don't assign its return value to something...

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in several ways, but I will try to give you as much of a helping hand as I can.

```
public void addInterest(String topic, int level) {
    Interest interest = new Interest(topic, level); 
    /*YOUR CODE HERE TO ADD interest TO THE LINKD LIST*/ 
}
```

This is most likely the easiest way of doing it. But I don't know the context of your program. With the solution above, each time you call the **addInterest** method, all you need to provide is the topic and the level of interest.
You can get the topic and level of interest from the user.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp

Hope this helps! Ask away if this did not solve your problem